# How to send Image File inside JSONObject using Retrofit 2.3?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, multipart

I am facing a issue from long time. I have to send JSONObject that contains arrays and files types of data. But I not getting how could I send this type of data to server. The data that I need to send to server is mentioned below.

```
{
  "accessToken": "",
  "groupName": "",
  "startLocation": [
    36.15, 76.32
  ],
  "rideDate": "",
  "coverPic": "file"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit 2 : send files with json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254451/retrofit-2-send-files-with-json-object)

Comment: @NileshRathod I liked your confidence but atleast you must checkout your answer 1 time before voting down my question. 
Do you know RequestBody.create() donot allows array.

Answer (score 1):

Try yo upload the data as multipart sing retrofit since you have both image files and extra json parameters.

Hope this suggestion may help you!